# How do you use phrase named "get along "?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I have learned one English phrase recently but i am facing doubt of it's using.

According to dictionary "get along" means be friend or deal with something.
So aren't these question right written below?

★i can easily get along with friends.
★ our government fails get along with the situation.
★ Do you get along with your friends?

★Communication skills help you to get along with peoples.
Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to ask whether someone gets along with their friends, because if they didn't get along they would not be friends.

Comment: You might speak of getting along with your neighbors. A government tries to deal with problems or address them, so the use of “get along” is unidiomatic there.

Comment: Just "get along" does not mean this, the full phrase is "get along with". The "with" is an important part of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

You would "get along" with someone at work or someone you are not friends with because you do not know them well enough to be friends. It means you have a reasonable relationship with someone you do not know well.
"Communication skills" (reading, writing, speaking etc.) has a wide meaning, beyond just getting along with people.

There is also the usage; "get along with you!" which is when you may have made an irrelevant or funny comment but the speaker is saying that you are talking nonsense or being unhelpful & is telling you (often also humorously) to go away. "get along..." They may not mean you to actually go away but they are saying they don't believe you.